# Shiny Image output not found

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

i am running this shiny app below and i keep getting the following error

```
Warning: Error in <-: object 'output' not found
  [No stack trace available]
Error in output$x <- renderImage({ : object 'output' not found
```

The app is displayed in google chrome but the pages are greyed out with features from previous code running, i assume this is because i havent fixed the error however i have tried to make the following code identical to what i did before and still get the error.

this is my ui.r code

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(bootstrap)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),

                navbarPage(
                  title = ("Printacles"),
                  tabPanel("Home", "This panel is intentionally left blank"),
                  tabPanel("Get Started",
                             sidebarPanel(
                             tags$h3("Input prescription:"),
                             numericInput("num1", "SPH:", ""),
                             numericInput("num2", "AXIS:", ""),
                             numericInput("num3", "CYL:", ""),
                             selectInput("picture", "Choose Your Frame:",
                                          c("Round Eye", "Wayfarer", "Square")),
                             br(),
                             submitButton("Submit")
                           ),
                           column(4,
                           imageOutput("x", height = 100)
                                
       
                  ),
                  ),
        

                  tabPanel("Pricing", "This panel is intentionally left blank"),
                  tabPanel("Models", "This panel is intentionally left blank"),
                  tabPanel("FAQ", "This panel is intentionally left blank")
                  
                ) # navbarPage
) # fluidPage
```

and my server.r is

```
output$x <- renderImage({
  if (is.null(input$picture))
    return(NULL)
  
  if (input$picture == "Round Eye") {
    return(list(
      src = "pics/Round Eye.jpg",
      filetype = "image/jpeg",
      alt = "Round eye"
    ))
  } else if (input$picture == "Wayfarer") {
    return(list(
      src = "pics/Wayfarer.jpg",
      filetype = "image/jpeg",
      alt = "Wayfarer"
    ))
  }
  
}, deleteFile = FALSE)
```

I have looked for answers but found no fix. If anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the minimal, running code for your shiny app. Right now I don't know if you've included `function(input, output, session)` in your `server` or not, what could cause the error. Usually, the error you get is from missing/wrong brackets

Comment: The space in `Round Eye` might be a problem when using `input$picture`.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the paths, have a look at the ` normalizePath` as per `plot3 `example on https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderImage.html